# postman window not visible when sharing desktop

Tags: linux-mint, screen-sharing, zoom-meeting, postman, flatpak

I have a linux desktop running on Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon and I am using [ZOOM](https://zoom.us/) application - specifically a [screen share](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/sections/201740106-Screen-Sharing) feature to share presentations and various content.

Until this point I have not had any problem what so ever but recently I decided to present controlling flow via [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) application and I cannot force it do display on the share screen.

Actually I can see it on my desktop along with the icon in tray, all other participants in the zoom meeting can see that tray icon but not the window itself. I tried to force it to stay always on top, pin it over whole screen, various attempts made but none of them successful. Neither google helps me here.

I found that if I am moving the postman window, I can view the top border of the window sometimes (in some kind of white color) but the rest of the window remains transparent.

Can this be somehow repaired?
Is there any electron setting that can cope with that (I tried other electron apps and they are showed fine) or shall I forgot to present with postman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a specific problem of a version stored in Linux Mint's Software Manger. It is a [Flatpak](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/introduction.html) installation that was delivered to the store in version 10.0.1 (Postman).

If I [Download Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) from official site (comes in universal "tar.gz" package for linux-64bit - version 10.0.8 as on 01/2023), I am able to present the app in our zoom meeting without an issue.

### Alternative solution

[Postman web interface](https://postman.co) that lets you work with the very same content as in above mentioned postman app. I am not considering it as a solution to this very specific problem but I can cover with that my needs for presentation purposes.